# Validate bool methods (constraints) in list

Tags: c#, list, validation, constraints

I'm wondering if this is possible:

I would like to have a list where I can add bool methods to and validate those methods and when they are all true, return true. When at least one is false, return false.

Problem is, when I do something like:

```
private int _value1, _value2, _value3, _value4;

private bool check2()
{
    return _value2 + _value3 > _value4;
}

private bool check2()
{
   return _value2 + _value3 > _value4;
}

List<bool> constraints = new List<bool>();
constrains.Add(check1());
constrains.Add(check2());
```

the bools added are of course the result of the validation when added to the list. I get that ;-)

How can I make a list with methods, that are actually re-validated?
Kind regards,

Matthijs

**This is what I wanted.**

With the help of the answers below. I made this. Might be useful for others looking for the same thing.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private int _value1, _value2, _value3, _value4;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConstraintsList cl = new ConstraintsList();
        cl.Add(check1);
        cl.Add(check2);

        bool test1 = cl.AllTrue;
        bool test2 = cl.AnyTrue;

        _value4 = -5;

        bool test3 = cl.AllTrue;
        bool test4 = cl.AnyTrue;

        _value4 = 5;

        cl.Remove(check2);

        bool test5 = cl.AllTrue;
        bool test6 = cl.AnyTrue;
    }

    private bool check1()
    {
        return _value1 + _value2 == _value3;
    }

    private bool check2()
    {
        return _value2 + _value3 > _value4;
    }

}
```

using:

```
public class ConstraintsList
{
    private HashSet<Func<bool>> constraints = new HashSet<Func<bool>>();

    public void Add(Func<bool> item)
    {
        try
        {
            constraints.Add(item);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool AllTrue { get { return constraints.All(c => c()); } }
    public bool AnyTrue { get { return constraints.Any(c => c()); } }

    public void Remove(Func<bool> item)
    {
        try
        {
            constraints.Remove(item);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
List<Func<bool>> constraints = new List<Func<bool>> ();

// add your functions
constraints.Add(check1);
constraints.Add(check2);

// and then determine if all of them return true
bool allTrue = constraints.All (c => c());

// or maybe if any are true
bool anyTrue = constraints.Any(c => c());
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible, you can define a list of `Func<bool>`

```
List<Func<bool>> constraints = new  List<Func<bool>>
```

So you can add your `bool` methods into this list:

```
constraints.Add(check1);
constraints.Add(check2);
```

So you can use the list like below:

```
foreach (var method in constraints)
{
     bool flag = method();
     ... // Do something more
}
```

Or use LINQ like another answer if you need

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Before the last edit of you answer, I implemented the solution Phil gave with the allTrue and anyTrue options. That's why I accept his answer. But thank you very much.